# "/usr/bin/env ruby" defaults to Ruby 1.8 when RVM is clearly installed and in the environment

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having an issue where I've built a script to send notifications through Boxcar. The script has `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` set at the top, but when SABnzb triggers the post-processing script it errors with the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- boxcar_api (LoadError) from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require' from /Applications/Sick-Beard/autoProcessTV/sabnzb-notification.rb:4
```

In addition, when I run the script from the Terminal it executes just fine.  Its only when SABnzb executes it in the post-processing.

If I run `which ruby`, `ruby -v` and `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` they all output the proper version of Ruby.

```
$ which ruby
/Users/ericc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
$ /usr/bin/env ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.16.13 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Anyone have an ideas on why Ruby 1.8 is being loaded instead of RVM?

Answer (score 1):

SABnzb is being started with an environment that is unaware of your rvm installation.  There are several ways to deal with this:

1. Be explicit about the ruby the script is calling. (ie- change the shebang to `#!/Users/ericc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby`)
2. Write a wrapper shell script that sets the environment before calling your script.  Have SABnzb call the wrapper script first.
3. Edit the init script that is starting SABnzb and add the rvm environment to it.  This only works if SABnzb is being started as user that rvm is installed as.
4. If SABnzb is being run as a different user than the rvm installation, install rvm globally or as the same user running SABnzb, then edit the SABnzb init script to have the rvm environment setting scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Does `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p286 --default` work for you?